# WebView doesn't load content on emulator

Tags: android, webview, android-emulator

I tried reading other topics but nothing worked for me so I am creating this new question.

I have an activity that contains a webView but the content doesn't seem to load (on emulator since this is the only 'device' I have now).

Here is my code:
    public class WebViewActivity  extends AppCompatActivity{

```
WebView webView;
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
String link;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    // Hide action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    link = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra(Constants.intentForWebView);

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this,"loading","please wait");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl(link);

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
}
}
```

Added LogCat

```
1-07 23:46:39.422 11215-11215/com.android.xxx D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
01-07 23:46:39.506 11215-11215/.xxx   I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
01-07 23:46:39.521 11215-11568/.xxx E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2167)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:54278386]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : BackFramebuffer::Create: <- error from previous GL command
01-07 23:46:39.671 11215-11220/.xxx I/art: JIT allocated 61KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
01-07 23:46:39.671 11215-11220/.xxx I/art: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
01-07 23:46:39.743 11215-11333/com.android.xxx.xxx 
E/EGL_emulation: tid 11333: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-07 23:46:39.743 11215-11333/.xxx W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8173c680, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
01-07 23:46:39.860 11215-11333/.xxx E/EGL_emulation: tid 11333: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-07 23:46:39.860 11215-11333/.xxx W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8173cd60, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
01-07 23:46:39.962 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-07 23:46:39.972 11215-11226/.xxx I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4437(348KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 65MB/65MB, paused 6.043ms total 30.859ms
01-07 23:46:40.294 11215-11215/.xxx W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 11215
01-07 23:46:40.536 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-07 23:46:40.624 11215-11222/.xxx W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.950ms
01-07 23:46:40.642 11215-11226/.xxx I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 325(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(7MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 7.109ms total 32.209ms
01-07 23:46:41.379 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-07 23:46:41.454 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-07 23:46:41.519 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-07 23:46:41.597 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-07 23:46:41.674 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
01-07 23:46:41.735 11215-11215/.xxx W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings in Logcat?

Comment: this is what i get:W/art:      Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2167)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:54098386]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : BackFramebuffer::Create: <- error from previous GL command
E/EGL_emulation: tid 11333: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

Comment: Can you post the entire logcat around that Error message? And can you edit it into your original question rather than adding it as a comment? Makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: i did so now ... added them to the original post

Comment: Just double-checking as well, does `link` get successfully retrieved from the intent? (i.e. when you dump it to `Log` you can see the URL in logcat). I find it a bit odd that you're using  `getSerializableExtra()` instead of `getStringExtra()`

Comment: Found the answer. So the problems since to be that it doesn't show the site if the site certificate is not verified. I just changed the link in the serializable to a different site and it worked. thanks for the help :)

Comment: No worries. Make sure you add that as an answer and self-accept to help anyone reading this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The problem seemed to be when loading sites without a valid certificate. Adding a url of a with certificate loaded in the emulator